# PowerElement footprint confusion

Tags: connector, footprint

I am attempting to use some of ERNI's PowerElement parts but the associated datasheet and catalogue does not appear to be clear on the associated press fit feet

https://www.erni.com/en/products-and-solutions/detail/225689/

Now an associated part shows the recommended hole size for the press fit holes but I cannot seem to find evidence this is universal across the family

Am I missing something in reading the parts darasheet

https://www.erni.com/en/products-and-solutions/detail/225683/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is stored in the Catalogue as oppose to the datasheet

https://www.erni.com/fileadmin/import/products/assets/DC0006949.PDF

[image]